# Prolog endless loop with Intersect predicate.(Scheduling)

Tags: prolog, scheduling

I have a base file which i include which contains many attends/2 predicates like the following.

```
attends(student_ID,course_iD).   (Example: attends(2222,CSD101).)
```

The predicate schedule_e(W,IN,E) :

-W is a List that contains 3 courses and represents a week of examination. For instance W = [CSD101,CSD102,CSD103].
What it basically does is that for a student takes all the courses that he has and intersects them with the W list and then Returns this List IN of the intersected along with the number of courses this IN list contains. IN list basically contains all the courses that the student will be examined on and E is the number of the courses this student has on the exams.

The predicate count_num just returns how many numbers in a list are greater than 2.

The last predicate:

W1,W2,W3 are week1 week2 week3 exactly like the above one.
Each findall finds all the courses for each student and for each week and then intersects them with the week itself so we can know for each student how many courses he has on the examination for each week. Then count_num counts how many students have more than 2 courses for per week and returns it.

If i run ?- schedule_errors([CSD101,CSD102,CSD103],[CSD104,CSD105,CSD106],[CSD107,CSD108],E). everything's great.

But if i run schedule_errors(W1,W2,W3,0) (so that it will give the schedule or else the 3 weeks for which the number of students that have more that 2 courses to examined on is 0), in this case it says out of global stack for which i raised the global stack and it seems that it enters in an endless recursion. It also notes that this happens in Intersect. How else can i implement this? What exactly is the problem.

(The first 2 weeks have always 3 courses each and the 3rd has 2 courses.)

```
intersect([],_,[]).
intersect([H1|T1],L2,[H1|Res]):-
    member(H1,L2),
    intersect(T1,L2,Res).
    intersect([_|T1],L2,Res):-
    intersect(T1,L2,Res).
%1
schedule_e(W1,IN,E):-
    setof(C,attends(Y,C), L),intersect(L,W1,IN),length(IN,E).
%2
count_num(_,[],0).
    count_num(A,[H|L],N):-A<H,count_num(A,L,N1),N is N1+1.
    count_num(A,[H|L],N):-A>=H,count_num(A,L,N).
%3
schedule_errors(W1,W2,W3,E):-
    findall(E1, schedule_e(W1, _, E1), Esa),
    findall(E2, schedule_e(W2, _, E2), Esb),
    findall(E3, schedule_e(W3, _, E3), Esc),
    append(Esa,Esb,L),append(L,Esc,L1),count_num(2,L1,E).
```

Comment: You keep using names like `CSD101`. Do you realize that these are variables, not atoms? Or does your code really quote them to make them atoms, as in `'CSD101'`? Also, please add at least some of the `attends` facts to your question.

Comment: [MCVE](/help/mcve), please.

Comment: attends(2222,c219). attends(2222,c210).